# How to select a specific pod for a service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have a kubernetes cluster of 3 hosts where each Host has a unique id label. 
On this cluster, there is a software that has 3 instances (replicas).

Each replica requires to talk to all other replicas. In addition, there is a service that contains all pods so that this application is permanently available.

So I have:

```
Instance1 (with labels run: theTool,instanceid: 1)
Instance2 (with labels run: theTool,instanceid: 2)
Instance3 (with labels run: theTool,instanceid: 3)
```

and

```
Service1 (selecting pods with label instanceid=1)
Service2 (selecting pods with label instanceid=2)
Service3 (selecting pods with label instanceid=3)
Service (selecting pods with label run=theTool)
```

This approach works but have I cannot scale or use the rolling-update feature.

I would like to define a deployment with 3 replicas, where each replicate gets a unique generic label (for instance the replica-id like 1/3, 2/3 and so on).

Within the services, I could use the selector to fetch this label which will exist even after an update.

Another solution might be to select the pod/deployment, depending on the host where it is running on. I could use a DaemonSet or just a pod/deployment with affinity to ensure that each host has an exact one replica of my deployment.

But I didn't know how to select a pod based on a host label where it runs on.

Using the hostname is not an option as hostnames will change in different environments.

I have searched the docs but didn't find anything matching this use case. Hopefully, someone here has an idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called [StatefulSets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/abstractions/controllers/statefulsets/), which just launched to beta with [Kubernetes 1.5](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/12/kubernetes-1.5-supporting-production-workloads.html) (note that it was previously available in alpha under a different name, PetSets).

In a StatefulSet, each replica has a unique name that is persisted across restarts. In your example, these would be instance-1, instance-2, instance-3. Since the instance names are persisted (even if the pod is recreated on another node), you don't need a service-per-instance.

The documentation has more details:

- [Using StatefulSets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/abstractions/controllers/statefulsets/)
- [Scaling a StatefulSet](http://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-stateful-set/scale-stateful-set/)
- [Deleting a StatefulSet](http://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-stateful-set/deleting-a-statefulset/)
- [Debugging a StatefulSet](http://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-stateful-set/deleting-a-statefulset/)

Comment: I successfully created a StatefulSet but after that i discovered that it is currently not possible to resolve the ip for a pod by name.

Comment: Ok, found the issue. The service MUST be headless. Then it is possible to resolve the pody by using <petname>.<service>.<namespace>.svc.<cluster_domain>

Answer (score 0):

You can map NodeIP:NodePort with PodIP:PodPort. Your pod is running on some Node(Instance/VM).

1. Assign Label to your nodes ,

   http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/
2. Write a service for your pod , for example

service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
  labels:
    label: mysql-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 3306 #Port on which your service is running
    nodePort: 32001 # Node port on which you can access it statically
    targetPort: 3306
    protocol: TCP
    name: http

  selector:
    name: mysql-selector   #bind pod here
```

3. Add node selector (in spec field) to your deployment.yaml

deployment.yaml:

```
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    nodename: mysqlnode #labelkey=labelname assigned in first step
```

With this you will be able to access your pod service with Nodeip:Nodeport. If I labeled node `10.11.20.177` with ,

`nodename=mysqlnode`

I will add in node selector ,

```
nodeSelector:
  nodename : mysqlnode
```

I specified in service nodePort so now I can access pod service (Which is running in container)

```
10.11.20.177:32001
```

But this node should be in same network so it can access pod. For outside access make `32001` accessible publicaly with firewall configuration. It is static forever. Label will take care of your dynamic pod ips.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I need to know the IPs or resolveable dns names of the other pods while starting in order for them to sync. They need to be aware of each other.